# Oracle: Return dynamic result set from sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor, pipelined-function

I need a pipelined functions that can return a table from a sys_refcursor in with the sys_refcursor parameter is unknown at compiled time.

for example:

```
select * 
from  table(pipeline_func(cursor(select 1 col_1, 2 col_2 from dua)))
```

or

```
select * 
from  table(pipeline_func(cursor(select 1 col_1, 2 col_2, 3 col_3 from dua))).
```

I have read the post 
[return resultset from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155844/return-resultset-from-function)

and tried to modify the code so that it can accept sys_refcursor as parameter instead of string SQL statement. But error happens at the line:

```
pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.execute := dbms_sql.execute(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor);
```

Error massage: invalid cursor.

Could you help me to fix the error or give me the hint to solve my problem?

Follow is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type dynamic_pipeline as object
(
     atype anytype,
     static function ODCITableDescribe
     (
        rtype out anytype, 
        sql_cur  in out SYS_REFCURSOR
     )
     return number,

     static function ODCITablePrepare
     (
        sctx      out dynamic_pipeline,
        tf_info   in  sys.ODCITabfuncinfo,
        sql_cur  in out SYS_REFCURSOR
      )
      return number,

     static function ODCITableStart
     (
        sctx  in out dynamic_pipeline,
        sql_cur  in out SYS_REFCURSOR
     )
     return number,

     member function ODCITablefetch
     ( 
        self  in out dynamic_pipeline,
        nrows in     number,
        rws   out    anydataset
     )
     return number,

     member function ODCITableClose
     (
        self in dynamic_pipeline
     )
     return number
 );


CREATE OR REPLACE package ICMDB_OAA.pkg_dynamic_pipeline as
 /*
  * Global Types
  */
  -- Describe array.
  type dynamic_sql_rec is record
  (
        cursor    integer,
        column_cnt  pls_integer,
        description dbms_sql.desc_tab2,
        execute     integer
   );


   type anytype_metadata_rec is record
   (
        precision pls_integer,
        scale     pls_integer,
        length    pls_integer,
        csid      pls_integer,
        csfrm     pls_integer,
        schema    varchar2(30),
        type      anytype,
        name      varchar2(30),
        version   varchar2(30),
        attr_cnt  pls_integer,
        attr_type anytype,
        attr_name varchar2(128),
        typecode  pls_integer
    );

    /*
    * Global Variables
    */
    -- SQL descriptor.
     r_sql dynamic_sql_rec;

     /*
      * function will run the given SQL
      */
     /*
        function querydb(p_stmt in varchar2)
        return anydataset pipelined using dyn_pipeline;
     */

     function querydb(p_cursor in sys_refcursor)
     return anydataset pipelined using dynamic_pipeline;

end pkg_dynamic_pipeline;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE type body dynamic_pipeline
as
    /*
     * DESC step. this will be called at hard parse and will create
     * a physical type in the DB Schema based on the select columns.
     */
    static function ODCITableDescribe
    (
        rtype out anytype, 
        sql_cur  in out  SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
    return number
    is

      /* Variables */
      -- Type to hold the dbms_sql info (description)
      r_sql   pkg_dynamic_pipeline.dynamic_sql_rec;
       -- Type to create (has all the columns) of the sql query.
       t_anyt  anytype;
       -- SQL query that will be made up from the 2 passed in queries.
       -- v_sql   varchar2(32767);
        -- cur_local sys_refcursor;
     begin
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITableDescribe');    

      /*
       * Parse the SQL and describe its format and structure.
       */
      -- v_sql := replace(stmt, ';', null);

      -- open, parse and discover all info about this SQL.
      -- r_sql.cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
      -- dbms_sql.parse( r_sql.cursor, v_sql, dbms_sql.native );
      r_sql.cursor := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(sql_cur);
      dbms_sql.describe_columns2( r_sql.cursor, r_sql.column_cnt, r_sql.description );
      --dbms_sql.close_cursor( r_sql.cursor );

      -- Start to create the physical type.
      anytype.BeginCreate( DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT, t_anyt );

      -- Loop through each attribute and add to the type.
      for i in 1 .. r_sql.column_cnt
      loop

        t_anyt.AddAttr(r_sql.description(i).col_name,
                       case
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type in (1,96,11,208)
                         then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                        when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 2
                         then dbms_types.typecode_number
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type in (8,112)
                         then dbms_types.typecode_clob
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 12
                         then dbms_types.typecode_date
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 23
                         then dbms_types.typecode_raw
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 180
                         then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 181
                         then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 182
                         then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 183
                         then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds
                         when r_sql.description(i).col_type = 231
                         then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz
                       end,
                       r_sql.description(i).col_precision,
                       r_sql.description(i).col_scale,
                       r_sql.description(i).col_max_len,
                       r_sql.description(i).col_charsetid,
                       r_sql.description(i).col_charsetform );
      end loop;

      t_anyt.EndCreate;

      -- set the output type to our built type.
      ANYTYPE.BeginCreate(dbms_types.TYPECODE_TABLE, rtype);
      rtype.SetInfo(null, null, null, null, null, t_anyt,
                    dbms_types.TYPECODE_OBJECT, 0);
      rtype.EndCreate();

      sql_cur:= DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(r_sql.cursor);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITableDescribe End');  

      return ODCIConst.Success;

    end ODCITableDescribe;


    /*
     * PREPARE step. Initialise our type.
     */
   static function ODCITablePrepare
   (
        sctx      out dynamic_pipeline,
        tf_info   in  sys.ODCITabfuncinfo,
        sql_cur  in  out SYS_REFCURSOR
   )
       return number
     is

       /* Variables */
       -- Meta data.
       r_meta   pkg_dynamic_pipeline.anytype_metadata_rec;

     begin

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITablePrepare');

       r_meta.typecode := tf_info.rettype.getattreleminfo(
                           1, r_meta.precision, r_meta.scale, r_meta.length,
                           r_meta.csid, r_meta.csfrm, r_meta.type, r_meta.name
                         );

      sctx := dynamic_pipeline(r_meta.type);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITablePrepare End');

      return odciconst.success;

    end;


    /*
    * START step. this is where we execute the cursor prior to fetching from it.
     */
   static function ODCITableStart
   (
        sctx  in out dynamic_pipeline,
        sql_cur  in out SYS_REFCURSOR
   )
      return number
    is

      /* Variables */
      r_meta pkg_dynamic_pipeline.anytype_metadata_rec;
      --v_sql varchar2(32767);
      --cur_local sys_refcursor;
    begin

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITableStart');

      --cur_local:=sql_cur;

      --v_sql := replace(stmt, ';', null);
      --pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
      pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(sql_cur);
      --dbms_sql.parse(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, v_sql, dbms_sql.native);
      dbms_sql.describe_columns2(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor,
                                 pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.column_cnt,
                                 pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.description);

      -- define all the columns found to let Oracle know the datatypes.
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITableStart. column_cnt['||pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.column_cnt||']');
      for i in 1..pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.column_cnt
      loop

        r_meta.typecode := sctx.atype.GetAttrElemInfo(
                             i, r_meta.precision, r_meta.scale, r_meta.length,
                             r_meta.csid, r_meta.csfrm, r_meta.type, r_meta.name
                           );

        case r_meta.typecode
          when dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, '', 32767);
          when dbms_types.typecode_number
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as number));
          when dbms_types.typecode_date
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as date));
          when dbms_types.typecode_raw
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column_raw(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as raw), r_meta.length);
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as timestamp));
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as timestamp with time zone));
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as timestamp with local time zone));
          when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as interval year to month));
          when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds
          then
            dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as interval day to second));
          when dbms_types.typecode_clob
          then
            case pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.description(i).col_type
              when 8
              then
                dbms_sql.define_column_long(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i);
              else
                dbms_sql.define_column(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, cast(null as clob));
            end case;
        end case;
      end loop;

      -- execute the SQL.
      pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.execute := dbms_sql.execute(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor);

      sql_cur:= DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITableStart End');

      return odciconst.success;

    end ODCITablestart;

    /*
     * FETCH step.
     */
    member function ODCITablefetch
    (
            self   in out dynamic_pipeline,
            nrows  in     number,
            rws    out    anydataset
     )
     return number
    is
      /* Variables */
      -- Buffers to hold values.
      v_vc_col       varchar2(32767);
      v_num_col      number;
      v_date_col     date;
      v_raw_col      raw(32767);
      v_raw_error    number;
      v_raw_len      integer;
      v_int_ds_col   interval day to second;
      v_int_ym_col   interval year to month;
      v_ts_col       timestamp;
      v_tstz_col     timestamp with time zone;
      v_tsltz_col    timestamp with local time zone;
      v_clob_col     clob;
      v_clob_offset  integer := 0;
      v_clob_len     integer;
      -- Metadata
      r_meta  pkg_dynamic_pipeline.anytype_metadata_rec;

    begin

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITablefetch');

      if dbms_sql.fetch_rows( pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor ) > 0
      then

        -- Describe to get number and types of columns.
        r_meta.typecode := self.atype.getinfo(
                             r_meta.precision, r_meta.scale, r_meta.length,
                             r_meta.csid, r_meta.csfrm, r_meta.schema,
                             r_meta.name, r_meta.version, r_meta.attr_cnt
                           );

        anydataset.begincreate(dbms_types.typecode_object, self.atype, rws);
        rws.addinstance();
        rws.piecewise();

        -- loop through each column extracting value.
        for i in 1..pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.column_cnt
        loop

          r_meta.typecode := self.atype.getattreleminfo(
                               i, r_meta.precision, r_meta.scale, r_meta.length,
                               r_meta.csid, r_meta.csfrm, r_meta.attr_type,
                               r_meta.attr_name
                             );

          case r_meta.typecode
            when dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_vc_col);
              rws.setvarchar2(v_vc_col);
            when dbms_types.typecode_number
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_num_col);
              rws.setnumber(v_num_col);
            when dbms_types.typecode_date
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_date_col);
              rws.setdate(v_date_col);
            when dbms_types.typecode_raw
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value_raw(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_raw_col,
                 v_raw_error, v_raw_len);
              rws.setraw(v_raw_col);
            when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_int_ds_col);
              rws.setintervalds(v_int_ds_col);
            when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_int_ym_col);
              rws.setintervalym(v_int_ym_col);
            when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_ts_col);
              rws.settimestamp(v_ts_col);
            when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz
            then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_tstz_col);
              rws.settimestamptz(v_tstz_col);
           when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz
           then
              dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_tsltz_col);
              rws.settimestampltz(v_tsltz_col);
           when dbms_types.typecode_clob
           then
             case pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.description(i).col_type
               when 8
               then
                 loop
                   dbms_sql.column_value_long(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, 32767, v_clob_offset,
                                              v_vc_col, v_clob_len);
                   v_clob_col := v_clob_col || v_vc_col;
                   v_clob_offset := v_clob_offset + 32767;
                   exit when v_clob_len < 32767;
                 end loop;
               else
                 dbms_sql.column_value(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor, i, v_clob_col);
             end case;
             rws.setclob(v_clob_col);
          end case;
        end loop;

        rws.endcreate();

      end if;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITablefetch End');

      return ODCIConst.Success;

    end;

    /*
     * CLOSE step. close the cursor.
     */
    member function ODCITableClose(self in dynamic_pipeline)
      return number
    is
    begin
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITableClose');
      dbms_sql.close_cursor( pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor );
      pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql := null;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODCITableClose End');
      return odciconst.success;
    end ODCITableClose;

  end;

/
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out lines 206 and 208 in the type body of DYNAMIC_PIPELINE and it will work:

```
--pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.execute := dbms_sql.execute(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor);

--sql_cur:= DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.r_sql.cursor);
```

For example:

```
SQL> select * from table(pkg_dynamic_pipeline.querydb(cursor(select 1 col_1, 2 col_2 from dual)));

     COL_1      COL_2
---------- ----------
         1          2
```

Before testing the fix run the block below to clear the package variables and force hard-parsing:

```
begin
    dbms_session.reset_package;
    execute immediate 'alter system flush shared_pool';
end;
/
```

You may want to base your code off of my [Method4 open source program](https://github.com/jonheller1/method4) instead of that other Stackoverflow answer.  Both versisons are based on Adrian Billington's original version, but I've added many helpful type fixes.  For example, the original version does not work with NVARCHAR2, float, 30-byte column names, etc.

Also, I'd be willing to add a cursor version to my project if there's a good reason to use cursors instead of strings and you think it might be helpful to others.

Comment: Thank Jon Heller. It run now.  Your Method open source program is real

Comment: Thank Jon Heller. It run now.  Your Method open source program is really helpfull to me. I hope you would add cursor version I can use your code right now and also others people. ^^